# getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null while doing gulp jshint in extract.js file

Tags: jshint, polymer-1.0

I'm getting the following error while doing gulp for my web app created in Polymer 1.0 .. i have used third party web component called akyral-details.

> /Users/PVT/Desktop/Sanskar-Marathi/node_modules/gulp-jshint/src/extract.js:14
>         file.jshint.extracted = jshintcli.extract(file.contents.toString('utf8')
>                                                                ^
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null
>       at /Users/PVT/Desktop/Sanskar-Marathi/node_modules/gulp-jshint/src/extract.js:14:62
>       at module.exports._.memoize.Minimatch.nocase (/Users/PVT/Desktop/Sanskar-Marathi/node_modules/gulp-jshint/src/fileIgnored.js:38:7)
>       at DestroyableTransform. (/Users/PVT/Desktop/Sanskar-Marathi/node_modules/gulp-jshint/src/extract.js:9:5)
>       at DestroyableTransform._transform (/Users/PVT/Desktop/Sanskar-Marathi/node_modules/gulp-jshint/src/stream.js:26:15)
>       at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (/Users/PVT/Desktop/Sanskar-Marathi/node_modules/gulp-jshint/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:184:10)
>       at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (/Users/PVT/Desktop/Sanskar-Marathi/node_modules/gulp-jshint/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:172:12)
>       at doWrite (/Users/PVT/Desktop/Sanskar-Marathi/node_modules/gulp-jshint/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:237:10)
>       at writeOrBuffer (/Users/PVT/Desktop/Sanskar-Marathi/node_modules/gulp-jshint/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:227:5)
>       at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (/Users/PVT/Desktop/Sanskar-Marathi/node_modules/gulp-jshint/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:194:11)
>       at PassThrough.ondata (_stream_readable.js:540:20)
>       at PassThrough.emit (events.js:107:17)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
>       at PassThrough.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
>       at PassThrough.Transform.push (_stream_transform.js:140:32)
>       at afterTransform (_stream_transform.js:96:12)
>       at TransformState.afterTransform (_stream_transform.js:74:12)

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to all this.. i don't know how to post the correct questions.. I'm new to coding..